# Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

My iOS app is developed with Xcode 7.3.

I want to use Xcode 8, and I'm using `Cocoapods` to generate project.

I don't want to migrate my code to swift 3.0 for now, I want to use Swift 2.3 for my project code.

Here my `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'xxxxx' do
platform :ios, '9.3'
pod 'RESideMenu', '4.0.7'
pod 'Alamofire', '3.4.1'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '2.4.1'
pod 'JSONHelper', '2.1.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '2.3.2'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '1.3.0'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '3.0.2'
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.97'
pod 'KVNProgress', '2.3'
pod 'CalendarLib', '2.0'
pod 'Charts/Realm', '2.2.5'
pod 'SwiftEventBus', :tag => '1.1.0', :git => 'https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus.git'
pod 'RichEditorView'
pod 'SwiftHSVColorPicker'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

Getting errors event if I set `Use Legacy Swift Language` Version to `YES`

Is it possible to update pods to Swift 3 version, and still use Swift 2.3 for my project?

Comment: I am afraid that this is not how this work. You can use Older version of these libraries old branch which are supported to 2.3 swift version.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you either use everything in Swift 2.3 or Swift 3.0. My tip for you is, if you don't wanna update to Swift 3.0, then search all your dependencies to look for a branch or version that supports 2.3.

P.S.: It's Xcode :)

Comment: Thanks ! And if one a the library doesn't support swift 3, can it be used in app ? Event if this library is in swift 2 version ?

Comment: From swift 2.2 to 2.3 there isn't major changes, if the Pod does not have Swift 2.3 you can try and convert it yourself :)

Answer (score -2):

Your can use pods like this :
Please add SWIFT_VERSION in your project settings and then update your pods like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'xxxxx' do
platform :ios, '9.3'
pod 'RESideMenu', '4.0.7'
pod 'Alamofire', '3.4.1'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '2.4.1'
pod 'JSONHelper', '2.1.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '2.3.2'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '1.3.0'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '3.0.2'
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.97'
pod 'KVNProgress', '2.3'
pod "CalendarLib", '2.0'
pod 'Charts/Realm', '2.2.5'
pod 'SwiftEventBus', :tag => '1.1.0', :git => 'https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus.git'
pod "RichEditorView"
pod 'SwiftHSVColorPicker'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3' || '3.0'
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

And then use install pods command.

Comment: I can't add SWIFT_VERSION, Xcode give that error : "There already is another setting name SWIFT_VERSION. Please enter a different name". However, this variable not exists !

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade ... you need to add this manually in Xcode 7

Comment: I will share you a link.. it will give you a good help.... wait a minute

Comment: This is exaclty what i've done.. may be the problem came from pod project ?

Comment: I will tell you steps which i followed... and its working fine for me....

Comment: First Step ==>> Open project in XCODE 7.3 and add SWIFT_VERSION in your project settings. And then close the project.

Comment: Second Step ==>> Open pod file of your project and add only platform :ios, '9.0' and then save and close pod file and run command to install pods.

Comment: My bad I was trying in Xcode 8. Should I change the libraries version to newest ?

Comment: i don't think so... please try one more time... may be this time it will work....

Comment: Third Step ==>> Again open pod files and add installer code and then save and again install pods...

Comment: Now I got this kind of errors on my libraries : "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: Yes but it's in library code, and if I made those changes, when I will make a fresh pod install, my changes will be erased...

Comment: Yes it will erase ... but i did't find any other way to do this.... so i am going with this option..... If you have any other option please let me know...